# Setting login page with other views with parent and child states - Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am new to UI router and new to Ionic as well. 
I am simply looking to create a login page with just a form. Then dashboard and other views will contain a common menu and a header from thereafter in each view.

I am not sure how to proceed with the structuring of the same in config function and my index.html.

**Note**: I know about angularjs app constructions where I used to have the common header, menu and footer directives for the similar thing in each view.

**Update** after Anuj's answer

My menu.htm - Is this correct ?

```
<ion-view>
<ion-content>
    <ion-side-menus>
        <ion-side-menu side='right'>
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
                <ion-nav-buttons side="right"
                >
                    <button menu-toggle-right class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
                </ion-nav-buttons>
            </ion-nav-bar>
        </ion-side-menu>
        <ion-side-menu-content>

        </ion-side-menu-content>
    </ion-side-menus>
</ion-content>
```

My Login view

```
<ion-view>
<ion-content>
    <h3>{{msg}}</h3>
    <h4>hflahfjasghf</h4>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

After defining config function as

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider
.state('app', {
  url: "/app",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/menu.htm", 
  controller: "AppCtrl"
})
.state('app.login', {
  url: "/login", 
  templateUrl: "templates/login.htm", 
  controller: "LoginCtrl"
})

.state('app.dashboard', {
  url: "/dashboard", 
  templateUrl: "templates/dashboard.htm", 
  controller: "DashboardCtrl"
})
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');
})
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.msg = "AppCtrl";
});
```

My app shows a blank login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download ionic template. in it configure app.js with stateProvider like

```
.config(function($stateProvider){ 
.state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/social/menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    }).state('app.login', {
    url: '/login',
     views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/social/login.html',
          controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        }
      } $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Anuj, But I have a few questions. 1. what does `abstract: true` does? 2. Since login is a child state of app, Won't it contain menu.html markup? 3. What wil be the structure of index.html in this case ?

Comment: 1  abstract - {boolean=} - An abstract state will never be directly activated, but can provide inherited properties to its common children states.    2.Menu.html is for Showing UI(Screen) of app Then i use login state so i changed my Screen by using login.html  3. Index.html contain all js file and css file with <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>  which is common . First install starter app,

Comment: 1 and 3 clear. But 2 remains unanwered. Anyway, I updated my question with what I have done so far and  It gives me a blank login page.

Comment: Index.htm being kept as same as you commented

Comment: or install app from http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/ .. install side menu app from here

Comment: See, my point of asking this question was if I can avoid repeating Header or any common functionality. But it seems inside evert partial you have done `ion-nav-buttons side="left">`> any way to avoid this ?  I have the docs with me but hope you get my question now !

Comment: <ion-nav-buttons side="left"> is just for placing toggle button on header on left side .If you want common menu  then put this in common header .